# Effects of energy loss for a damped wave

Tags: energy, waves

I have two questions:

1) When a lightly damped wave losses all it's energy, must it maintain it's wavelength before it dies?

2) When a travelling sine wave is damped, can the peaks be skewed from the original undamped sine wave or do they just decline vertically?

Comment: Your user name suggests you're familiar with D’Alembert's work in this area. Can you expand your question to indicate what parts of the treatment of the damped wave equation you're having difficulty with.

Comment: The problem is I'm not using D'Alembert's wave equation. I'm using $y=Ae^{-\gamma x}\sin \left( \dfrac {2\pi x}{\lambda }\right)$

Comment: If you're assuming that equation then the answers are just 1. yes and 2. no, yes because the zeros of the equation are in the same place as the zeros of the undamped equation. It doesn't feel like I've grasped what you're actually asking.

Comment: For 2), why must the peaks be centered to the peaks of the undamped sine wave if the zeros are the same? Also, for question 1), if the wave losses all its energy at a peak wouldn't it die almost exactly where the peak is formed ergo not completing its full wavelength?

Comment: Are you asking why one can't describe a function that has two parameters with just one parameter? As for the specific problem that you are posing, the zeros of the damped wave are (obviously) exactly in the same locations as the zeros of the undamped one. You are free to modify the spectrum of the damped wave in such a way, that it maintains the damping property, but that it also has the maxima and minima at the same places as the undamped wave for even strong damping... it simply won't be a damped harmonic function, any longer.

Comment: ok, but why are "the maxima and minima [points] at the same places?"

Comment: Have you tried differentiating the function to see where the extrema are?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know if the function is correct (hence my questions.)

Comment: Surely a damped wave has peaks that are skewed from the undamped wave because as it is formed (let's say a sine wave from the origin) it loses energy which is potential energy, therefore as you lose more potential energy you gain more kinetic energy which overwhelms the wave and causes the skewness.